# curl command is failing if space found in file name

Tags: curl, azure-devops, continuous-integration, filenames, spaces

I would like to upload a file **My test Live.ipa** to a server using CURL command

If I rename the file(My test Live.ipa) as MytestLive.ipa **without any space** it's working fine

```
   curl --request POST -T "/Users/durai/Documents/Test/MytestLive.ipa" -v --url  "https://testserver.com?requestid=1&token=hjasdfhkjasgnjyfsadg"
```

but if there's a space in the file name like in the below script then I get the below error

```
   curl --request POST -T "/Users/durai/Documents/Test/My test Live.ipa" -v --url  "https://testserver.com?requestid=1&token=hjasdfhkjasgnjyfsadg"
```

> curl: command not found

I tried escaping the space with back slash like below and it throws the same error

```
   curl --request POST -T "/Users/durai/Documents/Test/My\ test\ Live.ipa" -v --url  "https://testserver.com?requestid=1&token=hjasdfhkjasgnjyfsadg"
```

Again I tried url encoding for the space and I'm seeing the same error.

```
   curl --request POST -T "/Users/durai/Documents/Test/My%20test%20Live.ipa" -v --url  "https://testserver.com?requestid=1&token=hjasdfhkjasgnjyfsadg"
```

Any help in fixing the space issue is appreciated

P.S:
 - I'm running the bash script in azure devops CI/CD pipeline.
 - I can do a work around of renaming the file before upload but I intend to keep the name same.
 - I used CURL command with spaces in file name in my local mac terminal and it worked strangely fine but the problem seems to be occuring when I run the bash script in Azure Devops

```
   curl --request POST -T "/Users/durai/Documents/Test/My test Live.ipa" -v --url  "https://testserver.com?requestid=1&token=hjasdfhkjasgnjyfsadg"
```

Comment: If there's a space within the file name you have to enclose the path with double quotes. Moreover, you need to escape the double quotes with backslashes.

Comment: I uploaded a file with space-delimited name to a server  in bash task of my test pipeline. It worked fine for me. What is your agent specification?

Answer (score 0):

Azure may be interpreting the command and is loosing quotes and backslashes. You can try double or tripling the backslashes or one of these lines:

```
\"/Users/durai/Documents/Test/My test Live.ipa\"  
\\"/Users/durai/Documents/Test/My test Live.ipa\\"  
\\\"/Users/durai/Documents/Test/My test Live.ipa\\\"  
\""/Users/durai/Documents/Test/My test Live.ipa\""  
\\""/Users/durai/Documents/Test/My test Live.ipa\\""  
\\\""/Users/durai/Documents/Test/My test Live.ipa\\\""  
"/Users/durai/Documents/Test/My\\ test\\ Live.ipa"  
"/Users/durai/Documents/Test/My\\\ test\\\ Live.ipa"
```

Please confirm if any of them works.